# Re-projecting data to North/South Pole Azimuthal Equidistant view using Mars DEM Data

Tags: qgis, mars

I recently downloaded both QGIS and this DEM data from Mars:

https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Mars/Topography/HRSC_MOLA_Blend/Mars_HRSC_MOLA_BlendDEM_Global_200mp_v2

This is a low resolution version of the data found in the link above:

[image]

I would like to get these two views in QGIS:

[image]

[image]

How would I do that?

The two images above were created in Photoshop using the Polar Coordinate Filter. I cannot simply do the same thing to the high resolution data linked above, as it exceeds the pixel size limit for the Polar Coordinate Filter in Photoshop. I am hoping I can do this in QGIS so I can export it out from there.

Comment: This is a good one.  There are a few posts to set-up a Coordinate Reference System (CRS) for Mars - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368706/setting-up-crs-for-mars-images-taken-by-a-satellite.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254175/get-mars-dem-data

Comment: Thank you for the response Cary! Those two links helped me get the Warp (Reproject) function to successfully modify the DEM Raster layer. However, when using the "North_Pole_Azimuthal_Equidistant" or "South_Pole_Azimuthal_Equidistant" CRS, it doesn't give me the desired result. The north projection doesn't change anything, and the south projection is incorrect. I assume this is because those two CRS are using Earth data, instead of Mars data. How would I modify these to work with Mars? I am very new to using any GIS programs, so I am not entirely sure where to get started.

Comment: I do not know if there is a Mars wkt String for the CRS - this poat has the "gdal info" https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53838/isis-to-gdal-to-qgis-georeferencing-mars-images?rq=1   The WKT for every CRS tells you where the origin is, what the mercator rotation is, and the units and more...   I really do not know how to do this on Mars (or how to check the results).   QGIS has "settings\Custom Projections" that will allow you to modify the WKT or proj4.

Comment: https://lasp.colorado.edu/maven/sdc/public/pages/maven3d/